# Would this method be efficient at finding string permuations

Tags: c++, string, performance, c++11, permutation

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    string word;
    cin>>word; 
    int s = word.size();
    string original_word = word; 
    do
    {          
        for(decltype(s) i =1; i!= s;++i){
            auto temp =word[i-1]; 
            word[i-1] = word[i];
            word[i] = temp; 
            cout<<word<<endl; 
        }
    }while(word!=original_word); 
}
```

Is this solution efficient and how does it compare by doing this recursively?

Edit: When I tested the program it displayed all permutations
i.e cat produced: 
cat
act
atc
tac
tca
cta

Comment: I would comapre it against using [`std::next_permutation()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Comment: Start by considering *correctness*, not efficiency. There's no way the above code can generate all permutations.

Comment: This will take 2 * s^2 time. (it will bubble the first letter to the end of the list). It will basically show the steps need to reverse the word and then reverse the reversed word. This doesn't give you all permutations. You'll need at the very least (s! time to find all permutations of the word). I suggest just using `std::next_permutation()` on the string. It's correct and it should be fairly efficient.

Comment: [here](http://ideone.com/QloTcj) a demo with your code showing missing permutation: 1342, 1324, 1432, ... are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine tracing this code on the input 12345. On the first pass through the do ... while loop, your code steps the array through these configurations:

```
 21345
 23145
 23415
 23451
```

Notice that after this iteration of the loop finishes, you've cyclically shifted the array one step. This means that at the end of the next do ... while loop, you'll have cyclically shifted the array twice, then three times, then four times, etc. After n iterations, this will reset the array back to its original configuration. Since each pass of bubbling the character to the end goes through n intermediary steps, this means that your approach will generate at most n<sup>2</sup> different permutations of the input string. However, there are n! possible permutations of the input string, and n! greatly exceeds n<sup>2</sup> for all n ≥ 4. As a result, this approach can't generate all possible permutations, since it doesn't produce enough unique combinations before returning back to the start.

If you're interested in learning about a ton of different ways to enumerate permutations by individual swaps, you may want to pick up a copy of The Art of Computer Programming or search online for different methods. This is a really interesting topic and in the course of working through these algorithms I think you'll learn a ton of ways to analyze different algorithms and prove correctness.